# How to run Javascript files independent of HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, elasticsearch

I'm a super newb with Javascript...

How can I run a .js file without using code in HTML? I also needs the ability to run JQuery (ajax command) which is in the .js file.

I'm trying to test to find out exactly what is being returned from an Ajax command which runs a query on an Elasticsearch server.

Here is my code of which I'd like to see exactly what is being pulled:

```
var load_data = function() {
  $.ajax({   url: 'http://localhost:9200/inventory/_search?pretty=true'
           , type: 'POST'
           , data :
              JSON.stringify(
              {
                "query" : { "match_all" : {} },

                "facets" : {
                  "tags" : {
                    "terms" : {
                        "field" : "qty_onhand",
                        "size"  : "10"
                    }
                  }
                }
              })
           , dataType : 'json'
           , processData: false
           , success: function(json, statusText, xhr) {
               return display_chart(json);
             }
           , error: function(xhr, message, error) {
               console.error("Error while loading data from ElasticSearch", message);
               throw(error);
             }          
  });
};
load_data();
```

Comment: Use any modern browser with developer tools. E.g. Chrome on Win: Press Ctrl + Shift + J > Network.

Comment: Take a look at [elastic.js](http://www.fullscale.co/elasticjs/) it will make communication with elasticsearch significantly easier.

Answer (score 1):

`jQuery` is heavily tied into a DOM, so you might want to look at removing the dependancy on it.

That said, there is [a jQuery package](https://npmjs.org/package/jquery) in npm so you can run it via [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

You can try node.js. As far as I know you can install jquery like;

`npm install jquery`